# Как можно адаптировать классы с полями стандартных Java-типов к JavaFX?

Tags: java

Пример модели (сущности) с такими полями класса, которые удобны для JavaFX-контроллера:

```
package dev.example.model.entities;

import javafx.beans.property.*;


public class Person {
  private final IntegerProperty id;
  private final StringProperty familyName;
  private final StringProperty givenName;
}
```

Согласно книге "Чистая архитектура", сущности не должны зависеть ни от какого фреймворка. Это значит, что поля класса должны иметь стандартные для Java-типы:

```
public class Person {
  private final int id;
  private final String familyName;
  private final String givenName;
}
```

Но как можно адаптировать этот класс к JavaFX без потери возможности использовать функционал JavaFX? Пока не придумал ничего интереснее, чем явное присвоение полей одного класса полям другого класса:

```
public class Person {
  private final int id;
  private final String familyName;
  private final String givenName;
}

public class PersonForJavaFX {

    public PersonForJavaFX(Person person) {
        this.id = new IntegerProperty(person.id);
        this.familyName = new StringProperty(person.familyName);
        this.givenName = new StringProperty(person.givenName);
    }
}
```

Если полей мало - сойдёт, а если их сотня-другая?

Будучи новичком в JavaFX на момент написания этого вопроса, а не понимаю, зачем нужны `IntegerProperty` и `StringProperty` - в учебнике лишь сказано без объяснений:

> В JavaFX для всех полей класса-модели предпочтительно использовать
>   Properties ([Источник](https://code.makery.ch/ru/library/javafx-tutorial/part2/))

Comment: Покажите код где Вы используете эти поля как `property`.

Comment: @Tsyklop, будучи новичком в JavaFX, я не понимаю, что значит "использовать как Property". Я стал использовать `StringProperty`, `IntegerProperty` и так далее потому что так было сказано в [учебнике](https://code.makery.ch/ru/library/javafx-tutorial/part2/): "В JavaFX для всех полей класса-модели предпочтительно использовать Properties". Причины объяснено не было, а я пока в JavaFX ещё не на том уровне, чтобы критически относиться написанному в учебнике для начинающих.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Properties JavaFX использовать лучше, так как они могут автоматически обновлять пользовательский интерфейс при изменении. Вот пример кода,**Выводящего в консоль сообщение при изменении значения Property**:

```
yourProperty.addListener(new ChangeListener(){
       @Override public void changed(ObservableValue o,Object oldVal, 
                Object newVal){
            System.out.println("Property has changed!");
       }
     });

     yourProperty.setValue("new value"); Вызывается метод changed//
```

[Подробная информация об использовании Properties](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/binding/jfxpub-binding.htm)

2. Для автоматической генерации JavaFX Properties по предоставленному объекту сущности вы можете использовать [JavaBeanObjectPropertyBuilder](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/beans/property/adapter/JavaBeanObjectPropertyBuilder.html). Вот пример метода, позволяющего **получить JavaBeanObjectProperty из объекта сущности класса T**:

```
private <T> JavaBeanProperty<T> generateBean(String name) {
    try {
        return JavaBeanObjectPropertyBuilder.create().bean(this).name(name).build();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        ImageJFX.getLogger().log(Level.SEVERE, null, e);
    }
    return null;
}
```